# Filter XML with XSD

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've got an XML and its XSD file. So, the XSD says which are the required fields of the XML and I need to extract just them - basically a new XML with only the required fields (frankly, I need the nodes which have `minOccurs='1'` in the XSD). I am aware that I need XSLT for this but is there any way/application to generate an XSLT which will only extract the nodes that have `minOccurs='1'` in the XSD file.

Comment: There are some editors that let you save xsd files in xslt format, but AFAIK there's not a single editor that can also apply a transformation to the xsd file before converting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tricky to do this for an arbitrary schema. For example, you might encounter a content model like (A B A? B) where the first A is mandatory and the second is optional. Or, of course, you might encounter minOccurs="2". I don't think there are any short-cuts; it's a significant project. However, if you are prepared to soften the requirement, for example to only handle schemas written in a particular way or that avoid awkward constructs, then it could be rather easier.

Comment: well, i won't encounter minOccurs="2", that's for sure. I thought about using XPaths by Woody's suggestion. But there's a lot of examples you mentioned like (A B A? B*). I've also got XMLSpy, I'll tinker around with it a bit and see what can be done

Answer (score 4):

If you used the xsd file as a document and you had a simple structure, you could do it in one. So given a schema of:

```
<xs:element name="nodes">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="test1" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="test2" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="test3" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="test4" minOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="test5" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="test6" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and a XML file such as:

```
<nodes>
    <test1>blah</test1>
    <test2>blah</test2>
    <test3>blah</test3>
    <test4>blah</test4>
    <test5>blah</test5>
    <test6>blah</test6>
</nodes>
```

then this stylesheet:

```
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

        <xsl:variable name="xsd" select="document('so.xsd')"/>
        <xsl:template match="/">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="nodes"/>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="nodes">
            <allowed>
                <xsl:variable name="allowedNodes" select="$xsd//xs:element[@name='nodes']"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="*">
                    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
                    <xsl:if test="$allowedNodes//xs:element[@name=$name and @minOccurs='1']">
                        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </allowed>
         </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

would give you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<allowed xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <test1>blah</test1>
  <test4>blah</test4>
</allowed>
```