# Convert XML to previous XSD version with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xsd

I am looking for a few days without any success.

I would like to convert a XML file matching my last XSD version to a XML which would be validated by a previous XSD version. My first thought was to use XSLT.

But I would like to avoid to generate a huge XSLT file which would filter all new elements.

I guess this is something usual and it should be possible to make it quite automatically.

For instance:

Here is a first xsd version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="1.0">
    <xs:element name="Customers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Customer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="Customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Address">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="ZIP" type="xs:string"/>
                            <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Then I update this XSD to get a version 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" version="2.0">  
    <xs:element name="Customers">       
        <xs:complexType>            
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="Customer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                <xs:element ref="Animal" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>            
            </xs:sequence>      
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:element>   
    <xs:element name="Customer">        
        <xs:complexType>            
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Number" type="xs:integer"/>
                <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Address">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="Street" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="ZIP" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:integer"/>          
            </xs:sequence>          
            <xs:attribute name="Rate" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>        
        </xs:complexType>   
    </xs:element>   
    <xs:element name="Animal">      
        <xs:complexType>            
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="Age" type="xs:integer"/>          
            </xs:sequence>      
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element> 
</xs:schema>
```

And I generate a XML matching the version 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Customers xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Version2.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Customer Rate="24">
        <Number>0</Number>
        <FirstName>One</FirstName>
        <LastName>Two</LastName>
        <Address>
            <Street>Three</Street>
            <City>Four</City>
            <ZIP>Five</ZIP>
            <State>Six</State>
            <Country>Seven</Country>
        </Address>
        <Age>0</Age>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Rate="18">
        <Number>1</Number>
        <FirstName>Twice</FirstName>
        <LastName>Last</LastName>
        <Address>
            <Street>Kartofel</Street>
            <City>Berlin</City>
            <ZIP>4127</ZIP>
            <State>Berlin</State>
            <Country>Germany</Country>
        </Address>
        <Age>40</Age>
    </Customer>
    <Customer Rate="20">
        <Number>2</Number>
        <FirstName>First</FirstName>
        <LastName>Test</LastName>
        <Address>
            <Street>Roosevelt</Street>
            <City>New York</City>
            <ZIP>6521</ZIP>
            <State>New York</State>
            <Country>USA</Country>
        </Address>
        <Age>56</Age>
    </Customer>
    <Animal>
        <Type>Dog</Type>
        <Age>5</Age>
    </Animal>
</Customers>
```

I would like to convert my XML using XSLT to make it validated by my XSD version 1.0.
I know I can add the Identity Template and add a template for each new node or attribute. But I was wondering if some regular expression within the XPATH or anything else might help me to do it. I mean this sample is very easy (few elements to remove) but in case my XSD contains thousands of elements, is there any way to generate a XSLT easily?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your XSD version 2.0 is a mess. Can you format it correctly? Also, if you can generate XML based on XSD version 2.0, why not do the same for the first version?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your XSD version 2.0 is difficult to read, but as I understand the only changes in the new schema are more elements and attributes.

Note: The following is general advice, as general as your question. If you expected more specific answers, well, you know what to do.

> But I was wondering if some regular expression within the XPATH or
>   anything else might help me to do it.

It depends. Given that we do not know all the "thousands of elements" that you mention, two scenarios are possible: Either there is *regularity* to the new elements and attributes (i.e. they have a lot in common) or the changes are arbitrary and unrelated to each other.

**Remove similar elements and attributes**

If the elements and attributes introduced in the second version of the schema are similar, you could indeed "speed up" their removal (in the sense of not having to mention each single one in templates). For example, if all new elements are in the same, previously unused namespace:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:new="http://www.newnamespace.com">
  <xsl:template match="new:*"/>
  <!--...-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Remove arbitrary elements that have nothing in common**

In this case you will have to rely on the method you have found already:

> I know I can add the Identity Template and add a template for each new
>   node or attribute

But you do not need a separate template for each element or attribute of course.

```
<xsl:template match="Animal | Monument | Otherunwantedstuff"/>
```

Comment: @Luffy You are welcome. If it was helpful to you, please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I may have been not very clear. I am looking for an automatic way to transform an XML file generated with a XSD version to another XML validated by a previous version of this XSD. I would like to use my old XSD version to transform my XML to a valid one. For instance, I found this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307520/filter-xml-with-xsd which explains how to display in an XML only the mandatory fields. I was wondering if something equivalent was existing to transform an XML to be validated by a specific XSD.

Comment: Did you also read Michael Kay's answer there? Also, you did not answer the questions I posted in a comment above.

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are looking for a tool that performs the following functions:

- find essential differences between two XSD files (ignore spaces and CRLF(!))
- assess the impact of the changes on their respective XML files
- execute the changes in an actual XML file

[image: Comparison of two XSD files]

> Note: there is a fundamental issue if you remove the 'required' aspect of an element or
>   attribute in the new XSD that was required in the old XSD. Migrating
>   the new XML to the old XML may then result in the required addition of an
>   unknown value

So your function be an XSLT specification in the XMLSchema namespace, resulting in an XSLT specification in the target namespace.

The resulting XSLT is not a long and complex one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
       <html><textarea rows="20" cols="120"><xsl:apply-templates /></textarea></html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
       <xsl:apply-templates />
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customers">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Customer"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Customer">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Number"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="FirstName"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="LastName"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Address"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Address">
       <xsl:element name="{name()}">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="Street"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="City"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="ZIP"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="State"/>
       </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This template can be derived from the old XSD provided no element or attribute is removed. The XSLT for the old XSD must be using the specified elements in sequence of the complex types for each parent element.